# Symfony/Doctrine: Accessing unmapped(?) data within entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine, repository, entity

in Symfony (5.3.7 at present) I've got main data-entities and settings seperated. For example there is a user entity (default stuff), a TypeUserSetting defining the different settings and UserSetting which is m:n in between with the current setting stored.
namespace App\Entity;

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=TypeUserSettingRepository::class)
 */
class TypeUserSetting
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=200)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=UserSetting::class, mappedBy="setting")
     */
    private $userSettings;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $default_value;
```

and

```
class UserSetting
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=4000, nullable=true)
     */
    private $value;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=User::class, inversedBy="userSettings")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=TypeUserSetting::class, inversedBy="userSettings",cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $setting;
```

Thats not that complicated so far...
My problem is, that oftenly settings don't exist, because the users did not set them. In that case I want to use the default.

```
class User ...
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=UserSetting::class, mappedBy="user", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $userSettings;
    ...
    public function getSettingById(int $id):string 
    {
        foreach ($this->getUserSettings() as $oneSetting) {
            if ($oneSetting->getId() === $id)
                return $oneSetting->getValue();
        }
        //Not set, return the default
        ....
    }
```

And here we go... If there is no setting, the loop fails and I want to get the default form the coresponding TypeUserSetting. This is not mapped, so I have to get it from the database, but I didn't find a way to access that properly.

Possible solutions I found that far:

1. Insert the UserSetting for all users by SQL when adding a TypeUserSetting. This would avoid the whole problem, but I simply don't like that.
2. Adding a static method to the TypeUserSetting-repo to get the value. I think that's ugly and somehow going back to last century...
3. Inject the TypeUserSetting-repo by LifeCycle-hooks which (in my oppinion) isn't the way entities should be used.
4. Injecting the repo from the controller that calls the function... I think this would be the opposite of encapsulation and separation of concerns. (and I think about hitting my head to the wall, just for having this kind of thoughts)

Anybody got a good idea to solve that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you use an event listener to listen on persist?

Comment: This is not used on persisting. When editing the user, I get all the defaults, show and store them. This is used when a users is working and I have to use some of his settings. If there is not setting, I want the default.

Comment: I wouldnt do that in the User Entity. Introduce a service `UserService` instead that depends on `UserRepository` and `TypeUserSettingRepository` and implements a method `getSettings(User $user)`. Inside of that method you have access to all available types of settings (including their default) and you have the User and the settings he already has.